# How does forgiving others affect us

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, forgiving-mechilah

If we forgive others does this mean God forgives us when we sin in a way we can’t rectify or often don’t rectify the issue?

Comment: כׇּל הַמַּעֲבִיר עַל מִדּוֹתָיו — מַעֲבִירִין לוֹ עַל כׇּל פְּשָׁעָיו

Comment: I don’t read Hebrew sorry

Comment: Whoever forgoes his reckonings with others (for injustices done to him), the heavenly court in turn forgoes punishment for all his sins

Answer (score 2):

The ArtScroll version of the Gemara in Yoma 23a says (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/94608/27180)):

> But didn’t Rava say: With regard to whoever forgoes his reckonings
> with others for injustices done to him, the heavenly court in turn
> forgoes punishment for all his sins?

The ArtScroll version has a footnote, which quotes [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.23a.4?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) in saying that if a person who has been wronged by another, forgives that person, and thus he relinquished his right to exact retribution for the wrongs done to him, **G-ds attribute of Justice will relinquishes its right to exaxt punishments for the sin(s) that person did.**

In a similair vein, in Tomer Devorah, it is explained that:

> When a person who was offended accepts an apology from the wrongdoer, overlooks an offense and agrees to restore a friendship to its previous state, even though the damage was not corrected, **Hashem in turn accepts the teshuvah of the Jewish people. He forgives our sins entirely**, and His love for us grows to a level even higher than it was before we sinned [(The Elucidated Tomer Devorah, p. 106 by Rabbi Shmuel Meir Riachi)](https://www.feldheim.com/elucidated-tomer-devorah-1)